# how to remove/rename an extension from a folder

Tags: find, for

I have a few folders like name1@domain.com, name2@domain.com, name3@domain.com. i want to rename them so that it will be name1, name2, name3 etc. i figured out that if they are vise versa i.e name1, name2, name3 i can move it to name1@domain.com by running

```
find . -type d -name "*" -depth 1 | while read d; do  mv "$d" "$d@domain.com"; done
```

But how do i do the reverse? name1@domain.com ==> name1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a shell such as Bash:

```
for d in ./*@*/; do mv "$d" "${d%@*}"; done
```

`for d in ./*@*/` loops over all directories in the current directory whose names contain “@”. `${d%@*}` is a parameter expansion, giving the value of the `d` variable minus the last “@” and whatever follows.

You can make this more restrictive, *e.g.*

```
for d in ./*@domain.com/; do mv "$d" "${d%@*}"; done
```